# "the provided key element does not match the schema" in the sample from AWS Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Im following the instruction from AWS Android SDK,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-query-app-data.html
 but when I perform the `mapper.save()` method, it always throws

`07-10 11:47:28.966: E/AndroidRuntime(2030):`

`com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does not`

```
match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400;
```

`Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID:`

[image]

here's my table :

[image]

and my Book Model code:

```
package com.example.qingzhong.awssample.dbresources;


import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBIndexHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBIndexRangeKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBTable;

/**
 * Created by qingzhong on 10/7/15.
 */



@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Books")
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int price;
    private String isbn;
    private Boolean hardCover;

    @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "Title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "Author")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Price")
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "ISBN")
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Hardcover")
    public Boolean getHardCover() {
        return hardCover;
    }

    public void setHardCover(Boolean hardCover) {
        this.hardCover = hardCover;
    }
}
```

and my code in the MainActivity , just use the mapper.save() method,nothing fancy:

[image]

**I don't know what goes wrong, since all the required attributes are added in the Book.class, and actually Im following the instruction from AWS Mobile SDK**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I worked it out, the Picture from the link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-query-app-data.html

is actually misleading, if you want to use the ISBN as hash key in the code, you need to specify

**1.Select Hash as the primary key type.
2.For the hash attribute name, ensure that String is selected and enter ISBN. Click Continue.**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion Qing.  I agree this is misleading, and we will correct the documentation soon.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: so what did you change..?

Comment: select Hash as the primary key type.